# Instanced generic class throw "is not a constructor"

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, typeerror

im trying to instance a class passed as parameter to another, I have this in one file, ImportedClass.ts:

```
export default class ImportedClass {
  public constructor() {
  }
  public async exampleMethod() {
    return "hey";
  }
}
```

And this in another, InstanceClass.ts:

```
interface GenericInterface<T> {
  new(): T;
}

export default class InstanceClass <T extends { exampleMethod() }> {
  private c: GenericInterface<T>;
  public constructor(c: GenericInterface<T>) {
  }
  async work() {
    const instanceTry = new this.c();
    instanceTry.exampleMethod();
  }
}
```

And this in another, ClassCaller.ts:

```
import ImportedClass from './ImportedClass';
import ImportedClass from './InstanceClass';

const simulator = new InstanceClass (ImportedClass);
```

Then when I call it like this:

```
simulator.work();
```

It throw this error:

```
this.c is not a constructor
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be assigning `this.c` in the constructor?

Comment: This worked, thanks mate, you saved me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to actually use the constructor parameter!

```
private c: GenericInterface<T>;
public constructor(c: GenericInterface<T>) {
}
```

You missed this:

```
private c: GenericInterface<T>;
public constructor(c: GenericInterface<T>) {
   this.c = c;
}
```

And you could do this instead... auto map!

```
public constructor(private c: GenericInterface<T>) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You messed `InstanceClass` definition up a bit. It should be like the following:

```
export default class InstanceClass <T extends { exampleMethod() }> {
    constructor(private c: GenericInterface<T>) {
    }
    async work() {
        const instanceTry = new this.c();
        instanceTry.exampleMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited a little bit, but im getting the same error, thanks for the answer.

Comment: Of course you're getting the same error because still `c` parameter in the constructor has nothing to do with `c` field of your class. This is what it complains about, and this is what my answer fixes.